# set geo_point for location within array of data

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Hi i have data in elastic search like this

```
"id": "edff12sd3"
"main_array": [
{
    "id": "2308",
    "name": "Grey Area",
    "location": {
      "lat": 28.5696577,
      "lon": 77.3229933
     }
}
,
{
    "id": "2274",
    "name": "Tribute to The Beatles by Atul Ahuja- Live Music",
    "location": {
      "lat": 29.5696577,
      "lon": 77.3229933
     }
}
```

and i have set geo_point index like this

```
{
"mappings": {
"search_guide": {
  "properties": {
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}}}
```

It shows me error while i query like this

```
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "5000km",
      "location": {
        "lat": 28.6139391,
        "lon": 77.20902120000005
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "area",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}},"from": 0,"size": 20}
```

**Error**
    "type": "query_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to find geo_point field [location]"

thanks. please help

Comment: by distance from where ?

Comment: from my current location i will passed latitude and longitude in geo_distance search query after this all stuff... but firstly i have to set geo_point for this location field within main_array, which i am unable to put

Comment: google "Haversine" or "Vincenty"

Comment: hey mark, can you please provide me any example link to set geo_point for location within array object ??

Comment: See an example here ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436614/geo-point-for-location-field-within-array-field