# geo_point for location field within array field

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have data in elasticsearch like this

```
"id": "edff12sd3"
"main_array": [
{
"id": "2308",
"name": "Grey Area",
"location": {
  "lat": 28.5696577,
  "lon": 77.3229933
 }
}
,
{
"id": "2274",
"name": "Tribute to The Beatles by Atul Ahuja- Live Music",
"location": {
  "lat": 29.5696577,
  "lon": 77.3229933
 }
}
```

Now i want to set geo_point for location field. I have tried in this way

```
{
"mappings": {
"search_data": {
  "properties": {
    "main_array.location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

but it throws me error

```
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "Field name [main_array.location] cannot contain '.'"
```

can you please help me out. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location` is a property of the objects you store in `main_array`, so try like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "search_data": {
      "properties": {
        "main_array": {
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that as of ES 2.0 [field names may not contain dots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_field_names_may_not_contain_dots)

Comment: val i have one more question, can i check main_array that its lat long data exists within 50km ?

Comment: It would be best to ask another question since the subject is not related.